# Prove positive semidefiniteness of a special matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I have strong suspicion that the following is true, though I am stuck in proving it;

Two matrices $A , B $ are positve semidefinite while $M$ is positive definite, meaning that they are all square, symmetric and have nonnegative eigenvalues, in particular $M$ has all positive eigenvalues.
Then $AMB + BMA$ is symmetric, and I ***think*** that its eigenvalues are nonnegative. That would make $AMB + BMA$ positive semidefinite, which would make me happy!

Any ideas if it is possible to prove, or disproove?

---

I have considered using the weak majorization of Hermitian matrices, but I am not able to apply it to the matrix triplet above ...

Furthermore, since $AMB + BMA$ is symmetric, it is unitary diaonalizable to a real diagonal matrix, i.e. equals

$$U^T D U = (U^T D^{1/2}) (D^{1/2}U) $$

thus also being decomposable to the form $P^* P$, thus being positive semidefinite - does this hold? **NO**, since the matrix $D$ could have negative values, thus not possible to split up into real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, unfortunately, you are wrong.

Consider the following matrices:

\begin{align}
  A &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} &
  B &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} &
  M &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

They do follow your requierements but:
\begin{equation}
  C = AMB + BMA = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
is not PSD. Its determinent is negative $\det C = -1$ which means that both eigenvalues have of opposite signs.

Comment: Ok, thanks, good example. How about if we assume that $A$ is positive definite?

Comment: It still does not work.
Consider:
\begin{equation} A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
And the same $B$ and $M$.

Comment: Alright, appreciate it. I decided to make a new Q, with more detailed assumptions; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568987/prove-positive-semidefiniteness-of-an-extra-special-matrix-product