# Prove positive semidefiniteness of an *extra* special matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I have some suspicion that the following is true, though I am stuck in proving it;

A matrix $A$ is positve definite while $B$ is positive semidefinite, meaning that they are both square, symmetric and have nonnegative eigenvalues, in particular $A$ has all positive eigenvalues.

Assume that $M = A + B$, then $M$ is positive definite, so is $M^{-1}$.
Then $AM^{-1}B + BM^{-1}A$ is symmetric, and I ***think*** that its eigenvalues are nonnegative. That would make $AM^{-1}B + BM^{-1}A$ positive semidefinite, which would make me happy!

Any ideas if it is possible to prove, or disproove?

Comment: First thing I would do would be write some code to generate several thousand matrices like the ones you describe and make sure that all of them have positive eigenvalues. If not, saves a massive amount of time. It's a lot easier to put a lot of time into solving something you think is likely true.

Comment: Good idea, I kind of already did this though, but perhaps it could be done more generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For any $t>0$, define $B_t=B+tI$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
A(A+B)^{-1}B+B(A+B)^{-1}A
&=\lim_{t\to0^+}\left[A(A+B_t)^{-1}B_t+B_t(A+B_t)^{-1}A\right]\\
&=\lim_{t\to0^+}2(A^{-1}+B_t^{-1})^{-1}\\
&\succeq0
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Very neat! The sum of $A^{-1}$ and $B_t^{-1}$ is pos. def., then so is its inverse, and all these inverses are continuous in $t$. Thanks! Curious to see other solutions too.